# How to apply short time series linear regression over a large time series DataFrame

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, coefficients

I have a large time series data set covering multiple years with daily rates. I'm trying add two extra columns which include the Y intercept and the coefficient of x or slope based on the previous 10 days of rates.

In excel, I use the linest function to calculate the Y intercept and the coefficient of x or slope.

I would like to replicate this in Python.

I've included some sample code for this question.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='7/1/2018', end='08/31/2018', freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(76, 100, size=(len(date_rng)))

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I expect to see the following results

```
datetime    data    Slope   Intercept
1/07/2018   93  NaN NaN
2/07/2018   91  NaN NaN
3/07/2018   76  NaN NaN
5/07/2018   78  NaN NaN
6/07/2018   86  NaN NaN
7/07/2018   94  NaN NaN
8/07/2018   97  NaN NaN
9/07/2018   97  NaN NaN
10/07/2018  96  1.303030303 81.93333333
11/07/2018  82  1.175757576 81.53333333
12/07/2018  95  1.757575758 78.73333333
13/07/2018  95  1.290909091 83.2
14/07/2018  81  0.296969697 88.46666667
15/07/2018  84  -0.842424242    95.33333333
16/07/2018  77  -1.903030303    100.2666667
17/07/2018  78  -2.266666667    100.6666667
```

Comment: Check out the [`df.rolling()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @alkasm you can could use Pandas' [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function. On the rolling window you could `apply` Numpy's [`linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

```
A = np.vstack([ np.arange(10), np.ones(len(x))]).T

df['slope'] = df['data'].rolling(10).apply(lambda y: np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0][0])
df['intercept'] = df['data'].rolling(10).apply(lambda y: np.linalg.lstsq(A, y)[0][1])
```

To visualize the result you could use matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

pd.plotting.register_matplotlib_converters()

plt.plot(df.index, df.data)
for i in range(0, len(df) - 10 , 10):
    m, c = df.iloc[10 + i][['slope', 'intercept']]
    plt.plot([df.index[0 + i], df.index[10 + i]], [c, c + 10 * m])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Maximilian Peters.  If the dataframe has multiple columns, how would I adjust your solution so it doesn't just use the df['data'] ?

Comment: You could create multiple `slope` and `intercept` columns, one for each column of interest.